# C# emit call to generic method

Tags: c#, generics, cil, reflection.emit

Having the class

```
class C
{
    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return default;
    }

    public void M()
    {
        int i = this.Get<Int32>();
    }
}
```

I want to generate the body of `M` at runtime using `Reflection.Emit` and `ILGenerator` so that it exactly resembles what is shown above.

---

What I tried is

```
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(C).GetMethod(nameof(C.Get), BindingFlags.Instance));
```

which yields

```
ldarg.0
call instance !!0 C::Get<M0>(string)
//                       ^^
ret
```

but I need to get

```
ldarg.0
call instance !!0 C::Get<int32>(string)
//                       ^^^^^
ret
```

(note the different type parameters in the call to `C.Get<T>`)

---

**When emitting a call to a generic cfunction, how do I pass the type of the generic parameter (i.e. get rid of the `M0` and have it say `int32` instead)?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to substitute the type arguments with [MakeGenericMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod):

```
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilGenerator.Emit
( 
  OpCodes.Call, 
  typeof(C)
  .GetMethod(nameof(C.Get), BindingFlags.Instance)
  .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int))
);
```